# Can't copy local file in linux to hadoop

Tags: linux, file, hadoop, copy, local

I just installed `Hadoop` on a VM linux system. Now I am following my guide book to copy a file from locally to `hadoop` (file is saved on `VM` desktop). here is what I did:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal filename.csv /user/root
```

However, I received message saying
`"copyFromLocal: 'filename.csv': no such file or directory"`

Can anyone tell me what went wrong and what should I do to make it right?

Thanks!

Comment: By from locally you mean your host or guest machine ?

Comment: no, desktop of the VM. hadoop is installed on VM's linux system

Comment: did you first copy the file from windows (host ) to the linux ( guest ) via shared folders or scp ?

Comment: no, the csv file was downloaded from online directly onto my VM desktop.

Comment: when you type pwd what do you get ?

Comment: After tying pwd I got 
/root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to be in your Desktop folder ( containing your file to find the file)

```
cd /root/Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods for placing file from local host to **hadoop's hdfs:**

**1)** copyFromLocal - as you have used

**2)** hadoop - hadoop dfs -put yourfilepath(local)  hdfspath